# What is the practical difference between atlas-run and atlas-run-standalone in the Atlassian SDK?

Tags: atlassian-plugin-sdk

The [Atlassian plugin SDK](https://developer.atlassian.com/docs/getting-started) is used to create plugins for Atlassian products.

The kit includes two programs, `atlas-run` and `atlas-run-standalone` that appear to perform the same task: run some plugins (including yours) within an instance of one of the products.

What is the difference between them?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Found it.

Per [this](https://developer.atlassian.com/docs/developer-tools/working-with-the-sdk/command-reference/atlas-run-standalone), `atlas-run-standalone`

> Runs an Atlassian application standalone, without a plugin project (that is, not requiring atlas-create--plugin).

...while `atlas-run` [says](https://developer.atlassian.com/docs/developer-tools/working-with-the-sdk/command-reference/atlas-run)

> Runs the application with your plugin installed. (Runs mvn amps:run.)

which presumably requires a local plugin project.